# ¿Cómo puedo saber si mi Foreign Key está siendo relacionada en otra tabla en DJANGO?

Tags: python, django

Tengo dos modelos:

```
class Groups(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class subGroups(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    precio = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Groups, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="cars")
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to="cars")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Quiero saber si X grupo tiene subgrupos o el grupo existe pero está vacío. Para luego en el template poner el h3 solo en caso de que tenga subgrupos

```
<h3>{{group.name}}</h3>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes acceder al contador de objetos relacionados (que en tu ejemplo es `cars`).

```
{% if group.cars.count > 0 %}
    <h3>{{ group.name }}</h3>

    {% for car in group.cars.all %}
        <h4>{{ car.name }}</h4>
        <p>{{ car.precio }}</p>
        <img src="{{ car.img.url }}">
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Donde pone `group` puedes poner `object` si no has cambiado el nombre de los objetos resultantes de la consulta a la base de datos.

Espero te sea útil.

Edición: como indica @revliscano en los comentarios, es más eficiente utilizar la condición de existencia:

```
{% if group.cars.exists %}
    <h3>{{ group.name }}</h3>

    {% for car in group.cars.all %}
        <h4>{{ car.name }}</h4>
        <p>{{ car.precio }}</p>
        <img src="{{ car.img.url }}">
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Realmente invocar `exists` es mucho más eficiente que invocar `count`. El primero deja de realizar su operación apenas encuentra un registro, mientras que el segundo debe recorrer todos los registros para contarlos.

Comment: También existe la posibilidad de añadir la propiedad al grupo dinámicamente en el modelo con @property, de modo que pueda recogerse en la plantilla

Comment: Sí, aunque si ello implica una llamada a la base de datos (que es lo más seguro), de cualquier manera se hará.

Comment: Si has incluido el contador como @property se resuelve durante la consulta y no resulta en una sobrecarga… a menos que estemos hablando de millones de grupos y subgrupos.

Comment: El incluir una @property solo hará un alias, un envoltorio, para una operación que igual se efectuará. Si dentro de esa property tienes `self.cars.count()`, entonces de cualquier manera se hará una consulta aparte cuando referencies la propiedad. Los modelos de Python son una cosa y las consultas a la base de datos son otra. Te recomiendo descargar `django-debug-toolbar` y experimentar por ti mismo ;)

Comment: Y el hecho de que sean 3 o que sean 5 millones de grupos, no es el punto. `exists()` sirve para chequear si existen registros en una tabla y está muy bien optimizado para eso. `count()` sirve para contar cuántos registros hay y está muy bien optimizado para eso. En este caso estás queriendo verificar existencia, por lo tanto `exists()` es la opción a tomar, independientemente de cuántos registros hayan.

Comment: Gracias por la concienzuda explicación. He aprendido algo y me será muy útil en mis proyectos. Eso deja la respuesta en incluir `{% if groups.cars.exists %}, voy a corregirlo.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que (al parecer) quieres, es efectuar una [reverse lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) . Django provee un Manager, el cual permite que, dado un modelo `A` relacionado a un modelo `B` a través de una foreign key en `B`, las instancias de `A` podrán acceder a todas las instancias de `B` que referencian a `A`, a través de:

```
instancia_a.b_set
```

En tu caso particular, puedes obtener todos los registros de `subGroups` asociados a un `Group` en particular, haciendo:

```
grupo_en_particular = Group.objects.get(pk=1)    # (Por ejemplo)
subgrupos = grupo_en_particular.subgroups_set   # Devolverá un Manager de todos los subgrupos asociados al grupo en particular de arriba.
```

Ahora con `subgrupos`, al ser un objeto [manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/#django.db.models.Manager), puedes aplicar cualquier consulta al él (como, por ejemplo, `subgrupos.exists()` para verificar si está vacío o no).

Como estás pasando el argumento `related_name` a la definición del campo `group` en el modelo `subGroup`, también tienes la posibilidad de usar ese valor (`'cars'`) para efectuar la reverse lookup. Es decir, puedes conseguir lo mismo de arriba, haciendo lo siguiente:

```
grupo_en_particular = Group.objects.get(pk=1)
subgrupos = grupo_en_particular.cars
```